D&D 5e 2024 Guidance FAQ
With the release of a new edition to the most popular tabletop RPG in the world, we can expect to encounter new users, new questions, and new challenges on the site. However, we've been here before and we have matured as a site in the last 13 years, so we have enough experience to anticipate some of these challenges. The purpose of this post is to provide some guidance for handling these challenges, based on feedback from you, the community (see here for more details about that process).
Below is the collated guidance based on community collaboration in anticipation of the release of D&D 5e 2024.

What tag should I use for questions about D&D 5e 2024?
We have created the tag dnd-5e-2024 for use with questions about the new edition.
So what about the old dnd-5e tag?
The moderators have renamed that tag dnd-5e-2014. Questions about the original D&D 5e released in 2014 should use that tag. The original tag dnd-5e should not be used anymore.
Can we update answers to dnd-5e-2014 questions with information from the new edition?
No. We are viewing D&D 2024 as a new edition, and just as 5e 2014 answers don't belong on AD&D 2e questions, we ask that you avoid updating old questions tagged dnd-5e-2014 with information from the new edition.
But wait, I have the same exact question for 5e 2024 that was already asked for 5e 2014, what do? Post a new question! New edition, new question. Your 5e 2024 question will not be closed as a duplicate of a similar 5e 2014 question.
It's unclear which edition a question is using, what should I do?
It has always been the standard procedure for this site to specify what game, and edition if applicable, you are playing when you ask a question about the game you are playing (system-agnostic questions are still a thing, but not what I'm talking about here). The new edition of 5e does not change that expectation, even if Wizards of the Coast is trying to blur the line between editions by talking about backwards compatibility. So what should you do when a question comes up and it is unclear which of the two editions it's asking about? Our standard guidance for this applies:

What should I do when a question does not specify the game system being used?

We are already well equipped as a site to handle ambiguous and underspecified questions. As outlined in the linked post, ask the question OP clarifying questions,  communicate with your peers in comments, or even just answer the question with a note referring to the specific edition you're answering for. Or if you think we need more information before proceeding, vote to close until we hear back from the author. Just don't start an edit war.
What tag or tags should I use for questions about comparing editions or migrating characters from the old edition to the new?
For comparison, use edition-comparison, and for converting or migrating content, use conversion.

"The original tag [dnd-5e] should not be used anymore." – It looks like [dnd-5e] is currently a synonym of [dnd-5e-2014], so [dnd-5e] can't be used as a tag anymore - well, it can, but it'll automatically be converted to the [dnd-5e-2014] tag instead.

Re. @V2Blast's comment, is there a discussion somewhere on why it was decided to make [dnd-5e] a synonym of [dnd-5e-2014] instead of [dnd-5e-2024]? I'm interested in the logic behind it.

@aantia The original plan was to not synonymize it and burninate it if people kept using it.

@aantia the Burninate plan was to force people to actually tell us which book they use and not accidentally tag -2014 when they mean -2024 because they don't know there was a -2014 some years down the line.
